# Biblatex: suppress colon after "In" for edited volumes

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'm using Biblatex with biber backend, authoryear-comp style.

Is there a quick way to remove the colon after the "In" introducing the title of an edited book (@inbook bibliography items)?

I've found the following command for suppressing the colon:

```
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}
```

But, while this works fine with journal articles, for items in edited books a period shows up replacing the colon after the "In". I would like no punctuation at all, just "In" followed by the title of the edited work.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}

\begin{filecontents}{testbibliography.bib}
@inbook{Adams1981,
author = {Adams, R. E. W.},
title = {Settlement Patterns of the Central Yucatan and Southern Campeche Regions},
booktitle = {Lowland Maya Settlement Patterns},
date = {1981},
editor = {Ashmore, Wendy},
publisher = {School of American Research and University of New Mexico Press},
location = {Albuquerque},
pages = {211--257},
}

@article{Blanton1976,
author = {Blanton, Richard E.},
journal = {Annual Review of Anthropology},
number = {1},
pages = {249--264},
title = {{Anthropological Studies of Cities}},
volume = {5},
year = {1976}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{testbibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's the output. In the first item, a chapter in an edited book, there's a period after "In". This is what I would like to get rid of. The second item, a journal article, is fine.
[image: references]

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please add a fully compilable (minimum working) example [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your post by editing it? It would help a lot to the solvers.

Comment: I don't at the moment get this problem using my own test data. Could you add the relevant entries to your MWE. Do this by placing the `.bib` file in a `\filecontents` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that you have used `inbook` (which assumes a `bookauthor`) for `incollection`. As a result you are getting a spurious `\newunit` after the (non-existent) author's names. Change to `@incollection` and all will be well.

To demonstrate, I have used a (not released) package I use which marks `\newunitpunct` with a small blue line and watches for `\intitlepunct` too (marked in red). As you can see, in your example there is a `\newunit` after the "In" and the `\intitlepunct`. This is where the bookauthor should be:

[image]

If we change to `@incollection`, the problem is resolved, no `\newunitpunct` follows the "In":

[image]