# Remove the colon after "in" in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

While using `biblatex` with `backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=ynt`, the entry

```
@article{Author,
  author = {Author, I.},
  title  = {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  date   = {1980},
  volume = {23},
  number = {6},
  pages  = {121--123},
}
```

gets formatted as

> Author, I. (1980). ``Title'' In: Journal 23.6, pp.121--123.

How may one remove the colon after "In"?

Comment: You've been a member of this page for over 10 years and you have asked 145 questions. Please start adding a [MWE(B)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/36296) to your questions and also have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting how to format code blocks in your posts.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/5001)? All that's required is `\renewbibmacro{in:}{in}`, no?

Comment: Off topic: But isn't it 'better programming syntax' adding the string as `bibstring` and the space as `bibunit`?

Comment: @Mico The questions are different, as one sees upon scrutinization. \renewbibmacro{in:}{in} does not resolve the problem, but lukeflo's answer does. So the question ought to be reopened, in my opinion.

Comment: Voting to keep closed. `\renewbibmacro{in:}{...}` seems to work just fine with your code fragments, so it looks very much like a duplicate. If you disagree, you should show code which does not work.

Comment: I don't think https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864 is a good duplicate. That question wants to remove the "in:" altogether. Here we only need to change the separator after the "in", which is much easier, especially since there is a dedicated macro for it. Voted to reopen. I half expected there to be a proper duplicate explaining `\intitlepunct`, but I couldn't find one just now, so I wrote an answer instead.

Comment: There is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509074/35864, which is the reverse and links to a pretty complex code example. Then there are https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175730/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172241/35864, which already assume one knows `\intitlepunct`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/668702/35864 comes closest to a duplicate amongst the questions I could find, but it is more complex because it is only about specific entry types.

Answer (score 3):

The punctuation after "in" here is controlled by the macro `\intitlepunct` whose default definition ([from `biblatex.def`, l. 178](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/24a94f8f608872e11d259d7c581fc90ea76542a5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L178)) is `\addcolon\space` to typeset a colon followed by a space.

`\intitlepunct` is explained as follows in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (p. 124, §3.12.1 *Generic Commands and Hooks*, in v3.19)

> [`\intitlepunct`] The separator between the word “in” and the following title in entry types such as `@article`, `@inbook`, `@incollection`, etc. The default definition is a colon plus an interword space (e.g., “Article, in: Journal” or “Title, in: Book”). Note that this is the separator string, not only the punctuation mark. If you don’t want a colon
> after “in”, `\intitlepunct` should still insert a space.

To get rid of the colon we can just say

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Answer (score 2):

I felt so free to take your code and model a MWE.

You have to redefine the bibmacro `in:`. I guessed that you might want to add a space instead of the colon, but other punctuations are possible:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Author, 
    author = {Author, I.}, 
    title = {Title}, 
    journaltitle = {Journal}, 
    date = {1980}, 
    volume = {23}, 
    number = {6}, 
    pages = {121--123}, 
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\addspace}} % <--! here the space is added

\begin{document}
Cite something\parencite{Author}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Lukelo "I felt so free to take your code and model a MWE." That is what I want will happen, when I ask a question without using an MWE.

Comment: Glad that it solves your problem. But in general, I agree with @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that offering a MWE is the task of the OP. In this case, it only took a few lines to create an example, but I wouldn't have done it if the question had been a little bit more complex.